# Prove that $ J \cap B$ is an ideal in the subring (B, +, .).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let (A, +, .) be a ring and let B be a subgring in A and J an ideal in A.

Prove that $ J \cap B$ is an ideal in the subring (B, +, .).

I am super confused about this question. Here are my thoughts on it so far:

Let $b \in B \cap J$. Then $b \in B$ and  $b \in J$. Since every element in $B \cap J$ belongs in $J$ as well, by virtue of $J$ being an ideal, wouldn't it absorb products in B? I think I am thinking of this the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ideals are simply groups with respect to $+$, that absorb multiplication with ringelements. So lets check these two conditions:

- Clearly $B \cap J$ is a subgroup w.r.t $+$ of $A$ as both $B$ and $J$ are subgroups w.r.t. $+$ of $A$ and the intersection of two subgroups is still a subgroup(of the same group), as you may have seen in lecture.
  But as $B \cap J$ is a group w.r.t. $+$ and it actually lies in $B$, it is also a subgroup of $B$
- Lets check the absorbation condition. Thus let $b \in B, x \in B\cap J$. We have to show $bx \in B \cap J:$

  - As $x \in J$ and $J$ is an ideal in $A$, it absorbs multiplications with elements from $A$. But $B$ is a subset of $A$, thus especially $b \in A$ and thus $bx \in J$.
  - But it also holds $x \in B$, and since $b \in B$ and $B$ is a  ring, so especially closed under multiplication, it follows $bx \in B$.
  - It follows $bx \in J$ and $xb \in B$, thus $bx \in B \cap J$. So $B \cap J$ is an ideal of $B$.